# How to get a bounding box from one cartesian coordinate?

Tags: javascript, bounding-box

I'm trying to get a bounding box coordinates in javascript from just 1 coordinate (latitude,longitude), then I could use it as viewbox in the [OSM Nominatin API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim).

For the red point, how to get the green points **for any area/country in the planet**? (Raw difference of 0.15 for example):

[image]

```
for (x,y) will be: (x-2,y+2), (x+2,y-2)?


function get_bounce(lat, lng) { // y,x
    // x-0.15,y+0.15
    //          x,y
    //               x+0.15,y-0.15
    var lng1 = lng - 0.15;
    var lat1 = lat + 0.15;
    var lng2 = lng + 0.15;
    var lat2 = lat - 0.15;
    return [lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't it be: `for (x, y) => (x-2, y-2), (x+2, y+2)` ? With code above you are getting top-right and bottom-left, but I guess you need top-left and bottom-right ??

Comment: Please do not include tags in the title.

Comment: @philipp: but y-2 will give you a bottom latitude (?)

Comment: Do not fix the delta-lat and delta-long (displacement). The area of coverage will vary when you move across different regions on Earth.

Comment: You give a code example but fail to say what the issue with it is.  What do you get? What do you expect?  Are you looking for a completely perpendicular bounding box?  Do you want to account for boundaries along the equator and meridian?

Answer (score 0):

The 1 of degree longitude distance varies as was said in a comment depending on the latitude you are at. Longitude is wider at the equator and narrows down at the poles, unlike latitude that has a constant size across the globe. To visualize this see:

[Visualize the globe](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616)

Another good reference that helped me was:

[Calculate distance, bearing and more between Latitude/Longitude points](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)

I had a similar problem. Here is the code I came up with to get a pretty good bounding box. Give this function a gps location string ("x.xx, y.yy") and "radius" in km and it generates the north, south, east, west decimal coordinates for a bounding box. This is in Java but should be easy to convert to another language.

```
    // Compute bounding Box coordinates for use with Geonames API.
    class BoundingBox
    {
        public double north, south, east, west;
        public BoundingBox(String location, float km)
        {
            //System.out.println(location + " : "+ km);
            String[] parts = location.replaceAll("\\s","").split(","); //remove spaces and split on ,

            double lat = Double.parseDouble(parts[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(parts[1]);

            double adjust = .008983112; // 1km in degrees at equator.
            //adjust = 0.008983152770714983; // 1km in degrees at equator.

            //System.out.println("deg: "+(1.0/40075.017)*360.0);


            north = lat + ( km * adjust);
            south = lat - ( km * adjust);

            double lngRatio = 1/Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat)); //ratio for lng size
            //System.out.println("lngRatio: "+lngRatio);

            east = lng + (km * adjust) * lngRatio;
            west = lng - (km * adjust) * lngRatio;
        }

    }
```

The above code give a pretty good approximation that can be off a mile or two depending on your latitude. If you want to be more accurate then you might take a look at the answers here:

[Geotools: bounding box for a buffer in wgs84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455020/geotools-bounding-box-for-a-buffer-in-wgs84/50706226#50706226)

See Eduardo's answer to this question. It seems like a pretty accurate solution.